# How to compare two strings in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

```
var url1 = 'dominName/profilePics/'
var url2 = 'dominName/profilePics/12345.jpg'
```

I want to compare above two urls. If any string comes after `/profilePics/` it should returns `true` value.

I using regular expression(RegExp) but i unable to get solution.

So could you help me out of this.

Comment: [`/dominName\/profilePics\/.*$/i.test(url2)`](https://regex101.com/r/2vuMFx/1)

Comment: hi.. @Olian04 thx for your answer. could you pls elaborate your answer

Comment: @Nani its just a regex. If you click on my previous comment you can see a demo of it working.

Comment: thnx @Olian04 it is working fine

Comment: somehow `/dominName\/profilePics\/.*$/i.test(url2)` will not work in JavaScript

Comment: I would recommend you change the title of the question to: "How to check if a url path is a subtree of another url path." You would want a more general solution as the urls to match might not always be known, or could change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Create a regex pattern with [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with this string:

```
var myReg = new RegExp('^' + url1 + '.+');
```

- `^`: matches beginning of input
- `.+`: matches anything (length > 0)

```js
var url1 = 'dominName/profilePics/';
var url2 = 'dominName/profilePics/12345.jpg';
var escapeReg = url1.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
var myReg = new RegExp('^' + escapeReg + '.+');

console.log(myReg.test(url1));      //false
console.log(myReg.test(url2));      //true
```

Comment: You would want to escape the inserted string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url1 = 'dominName/profilePics/';
var url2 = 'dominName/profilePics/12345.jpg';
/dominName\/profilePics\/[0-9]+\.jpg$/.test(url1);
/dominName\/profilePics\/[0-9]+\.jpg$/.test(url2);
```

Comment: [0-9]+ will be changed if there is possibility of alphabets character i.e. [0-9,a-z,A-Z].  I have assumes ".jpg" will be there if something come.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method to get the length of the string portion after the domain name:

```js
const checkURL = url => {
  
  return Boolean(url.substring('dominName/profilePics/'.length));

}

console.log(
  checkURL('dominName/profilePics/')           // false
)

console.log(
  checkURL('dominName/profilePics/12345.jpg')  // true
)
```

Comment: hi... @Ivan is there anyway to get solution by using regEx

Comment: @Nani check my answer!

Comment: this will fail the following use cases 
> checkURL('bla/dominName/profilePics/123')
true
> checkURL('bla/dominName/profilePics')
true
it also assumes the url pattern is already know. This is not a good way to approach the problem as even slight change in url would require changing the code. Check my answer for proper approach.

Comment: This code check length of url > length of 'dominName/profilePics/'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly in a more general sense, it is to find whether a path is nested in another path (is a subtree). This IMO would be the right way to approach it as you don't want your solution to be specific to the url strings provided, as they can change in the future.

Proposed solutions:

**Non-regex solution**: Ensure `url1` starts with given base url (`url2`) and check if after splitting on `'/'` the number of sub paths of `url1` is greater than those of base url.

```
const isNested = (url1, url2) => {
  return url1.indexOf(url2) === 0 && 
  url1.split("/").length > url2.split("/").length
}

> isNested('a/b/c', 'a/b')
true
> isNested('a/b/cd', 'a/b')
true
> isNested('x/b/cd', 'a/b')
false
> isNested('a/b/cd', 'x/a/b')
false
> isNested('a/b/cd/z', 'x/a/b')
false
> isNested('a/b/cd/z', 'a/b')
true
```

we can add a depth parameter to test for specific depth

```
const isNested = (url1, url2, depth) => {
    url1.indexOf(url2) === 0 && depth
      ? url1.split("/").length - url2.split("/").length === depth
      : url1.split("/").length > url2.split("/").length
  }

> isNested('a/b/cd/z', 'a/b')
true
> isNested('a/b/cd/z', 'a/b', 1)
false
> isNested('a/b/cd/z', 'a/b', 2)
true
```

**Regex solution:** Not recommended as it is difficult to read and modify.

```
const isNested = (url1, url2) => {
  let escaped = url2.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")

  let regex = new RegExp(`(^${escaped})(\/[\/a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`, "gm")

  return url1.match(regex) ? true : false
}


> isNested('a/b/c/d', 'a/b/c')
true
> isNested('a/b/c', 'a/b/c')
false
> isNested('a/b/c/de', 'a/b/c')
true
> isNested('a/b/c/de/fg', 'a/b/c')
true
> isNested('x/a/b/c/de/fg', 'a/b/c')
false
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const checkURL = (url) => {
  
  return Boolean(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1));

}

console.log(
  checkURL('dominName/profilePics/')           // false
)

console.log(
  checkURL('dominName/profilePics/12345.jpg')  // true
)
```